# Why can't TypeScript infer this generic type?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code :

```
abstract class Parser<Value, Context> {
  abstract exec(
    options: ParseOptions<Context>,
    internals: Internals
  ): Match<Value> | null;
}

class LiteralParser<
  Value extends string | undefined,
  Context
> extends Parser<Value, Context> {
  readonly literal: string;
  readonly emit: boolean;

  constructor(literal: string, emit: boolean) {
    super();
    this.literal = literal;
    this.emit = emit;
  }

  exec(options: ParseOptions<any>, internals: Internals) {
    // other stuff
    return null;
  }
}
```

But when trying to infer the `Context` type from a `LiteralParser` type, it fails :

```
type Extr<T> = T extends Parser<any, infer C> ? C : never;

type A = Extr<LiteralParser<string, unknown>>; // "any", should be "unknown"
```

But it gets weirder : When removing the abstract method `exec` from `Parser`, it works :

```
type Extr<T> = T extends Parser<any, infer C> ? C : never;

type A = Extr<LiteralParser<string, unknown>>; // "unknown"
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QPJmASwPYDskA8AKgHxQC8UA3gL4BQokUAkrsBArnADZIXX1G0ALJxgAYwAWxMpVp06cAEZJgCOOOBRx3OEj7xkHAgDUeAVwgAaKAGE87AB7AyVOlCjLV6zVAiOIcQAKdw8obAwcfAAuWEQUdCw8Qns2fxcrUI9MNM4eJFjWdjzeUIBKWNEJaTNuSzIAHyhcc25uAG46ejodPT4AGUxinkMUBAJQ2ss-ZwhcABM%20bxyAcygm8wWIADMciHnMj1SnYDoydLnFuKNxqes7B3TXUIQIOHm8bhAobiGOHliy1wK06Hle70%203wgAFshrElNhsNw3rhOqFxMk1OZNNgEEFfsNuIC1KsbDC4VAEUiUWVqFkoEhzJA8WVQWFgJJMEgAHQE-7cfh89Qdekcrnc8laSiStndDz%20QJBCJJGLXBKRZIEOC4EAkGw5YpcXiFXJGpC0txhKAAemt4Q5HAZwHM2229Nezs4zVaIo89G6QigAFFnONSPwiDN2AsDPFjNqQPrcNtHbYyAB%20OxQWK4CAANw4aMDAEF%20CG1ARBoTRsYgSsbJsANa4bAAd1wJBI7RtdoARAnezYkJJsK15pToL2my3272gA)

What is going on ? Thank you.

Comment: It's `any` because you declared `exec` in the subclass as accepting `ParseOptions<any>`. That means the actual `exec` method conforms to the signature that would be specified by `Parser<..., any>` so that's the type that `Extr` matches against. If you change the definition of `Parser` so that there is no `exec` method to match it against, then the result will be different, of course. Basically, your problem is caused by the fact that Typescript's types are structural, not nominal.

Comment: @kaya3 Well, that was it, indeed. It was in fact a mistake, should have been `ParseOptions<Context>`. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but the `any` type comes from your definition of `exec`:

```
exec(options: ParseOptions<any>, internals: Internals)
```

When you use the original type –

```
exec(options: ParseOptions<Context>, internals: Internals)
```

– everything works.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QPJmASwPYDskA8AKgHxQC8UA3gL4BQokUAkrsBArnADZIXX1G0ALJxgAYwAWxMpVp06cAEZJgCOOOBRx3OEj7xkHAgDUeAVwgAaKAGE87AB7AyVOlCjLV6zVAiOIcQAKdw8obAwcfAAuWEQUdCw8Qns2fxcrUI9MNM4eJFjWdjzeUIBKWNEJaTNuSzIAHyhcc25uAG46ejodPT4AGUxinkMUBAJQ2ss-ZwhcABM%20bxyAcygm8wWIADMciHnMj1SnYDoydLnFuKNxqes7B3TXUIQIOHm8bhAobiGOHliy1wK06Hle70%203wgAFshrElNhsNw3rhOqFxMk1OZNNgEEFfsNuIC1KsbDC4VAEUiUWVqFkoEhzJA8WVQWFgJJMEgAHQE-7cfh89Qdekcrnc8laSiStndDz%20QJBCJJGLXBKRZIEY5PGw5YpcXiFXIGpC0txhKAAekt4Q5HAZwHM2229Nejs4zVaIo89G6QigAFFnONSPwiDN2AsDPFjHBcCBdbhtvbbGQAPx2KCxXAQABuHDR-oAgvwg2oCINCaNjECVjZNgBrXDYADuuBIJHaVptACI4yAezYkJJsK15pToD3G822z2gA)